# Nonhomogeneous linear transport equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples

I am doing my first ever excercise sheet in PDE and stumbled upon following question:

> Let u be a solution of the linear transport equation in the non
> homogeneous case $u_t+b*u_x=f$. Let u have a compact support. Does u
> have to be $0$?

We had another example for the homogenous case where I could show that u had to be 0 because of the fact that it is constant on the line x-bt and because of the compact support.

Here I would say it isn't the case since this quality of being constant in the line is not valid anymore and the general solution is also dependent on the integral.
But I cannot find any counterexample, so If would be great If somebody could give me a hint/help me.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample is a bump function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function), and f defined as in the answer above would even be smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure this answers your question but it is true that there exists ininitely many such examples: Simply take *any* $C^1$ function $u(x,t)$ with compact support. Then, define $f(x,t):=u_t(y,t)+b\cdot u_x(x,t)$. By definition this is an example that fits the stated problem.